# Can i upload to CDN server directly in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I have been exploring the features available in Azure and AWS. The fact that most features is not available or not clear.In CDN part i have comparisson criteria like 'Whether I can push/upload content to CDN Servers like in AKamai.

I have seen the feedback program and find that Custom-Origin is not available(
Link : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/status/191761 ).But this one i could not find any link.Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Azure CDN currently does not support direct interaction (i.e. direct content upload, explicit or on-demand content expiration, etc.). It works [as advertised](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cdn-how-to-use/) serves files from Azure Storage Account or azure Cloud Service.

Comment: Thanks.I didn't notice CORS is available in Azure CDN. i think we can make use of it for Custom origin requirements.